# Hide certain sidebar buttons based on user roles?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I was wondering how to allow different roles to see particular side bar buttons based on their role using spring boot 5
I have ADMIN and USER, my ADMIN should be able to see "Manage People" button on the side bar while normal USER will not see anything on that side bar.

**sideBar.html**

```
    <security:authorize access="hasAuthority('ROLE_ADMIN')">
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link collapsed"
        href="#" 
            data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseMenu" aria-expanded="true"
            aria-controls="collapseMU"> </i>
                <span> <b>Manage People</b>
            </span>
        </a></li>
        <!-- sub-menu -->
        <div id="collapseMenu" class="collapse">
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link collapsed" href="#"
                data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseGroup"
                aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseGroup"></i> 
                <span>Show User Group</span>
            </a>
        </div>
     </security:authorize>
```

**SecConfig.java** (part of it)

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
    httpSecurity.csrf().and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/").permitAll()
        antMatchers("/landing")
        .access("(hasAnyRole('ADMIN')
        .anyRequest()
        .authenticated()
        .and()
        .formLogin()
        .loginPage("/")
        .successHandler(loginSuccessHandler())
        .failureHandler(loginFailedHandler())
        .permitAll().and().logout().permitAll();
}
```

I tried adding
`<security:authorize access="hasAuthority('ADMIN')">`
into sideBar.html but USER page still able to see the "Manage People" button on the side bar.
Is there anything I'm doing it wrong?
I'm new to this. Thanks :3

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Thymeleaf engine there is "sec" dialect integrated with Spring security module. [Here are details](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/springsecurity.html#spring-security-dialect)

From the link:

> The sec:authorize attribute renders its content when the attribute expression is evaluated to true:

```
<div sec:authorize="isAuthenticated()">
  This content is only shown to authenticated users.
</div>
<div sec:authorize="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')">
  This content is only shown to administrators.
</div>
<div sec:authorize="hasRole('ROLE_USER')">
  This content is only shown to users.
</div>
```

Keep in mind you will need to include Thymeleaf security namespace in the root tag before using it:

```
xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4"
```

Answer (score 0):

The sec:authorize attribute renders its content when the attribute expression is evaluated to true:

```
    <div sec:authorize="isAuthenticated()"> 

 <!-- The Content under this is visible when the user is login with any ROLE -->
    </div>

    <div sec:authorize="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')">

  <!-- The content under this is visible when login user is ADMIN-->

    </div>

    <div sec:authorize="hasRole('ROLE_USER')">

   <!-- The content under this is visible when login user has role 'USER' -->

    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to add this within your thymeleaf  tag

```
xmlns:security="http://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5"
```

Also, add below dependency in your pom.xml file:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you check whether the user is Authenticated and then check if it's role is ADMIN then display the content
i.e

```
<div sec:authorize="isAuthenticated()"> 
  <div sec:authorize="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')">

    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link collapsed"
        href="#" 
            data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseMenu" aria-expanded="true"
            aria-controls="collapseMU"> </i>
                <span> <b>Manage People</b>
            </span>
        </a></li>
        <!-- sub-menu -->
        <div id="collapseMenu" class="collapse">
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link collapsed" href="#"
                data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseGroup"
                aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseGroup"></i> 
                <span>Show User Group</span>
            </a>
        </div>

    </div>
  
</div>
```